# How to use resourcebundles with jetty?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, resourcebundle

### My question is how does one include ResourceBundles, in a Jetty project?

I have a webservice project named ServletEnvironment.
ServletEnvironment exports my service as an exploded war directory, containing:

> [war directory]/WEB-INF/classes/{ properties files }
>   [war directory]/WEB-INF/web.xml

ServletEnvironment implements classes from my JettyWeb project.
JettyWeb starts a jetty server as described below:

```
Server server = new Server(port);
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/test");
webapp.setResourceBase("[war directory]//");
HandlerList hlist = new HandlerList();
hlist.addHandler(webapp);
server.setHandler(hlist);
server.start();
```

Then lastly I have a Servlet project, Servlet is referenced in my ServletEnvironments web.xml as below:

```
<!-- Listener -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.basicservlet.BasicListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <!-- Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>basicServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Default Basic Http Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.basicservlet.BasicHttpServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <!-- Default Servlet Mapping -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>basicServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    <!-- 60 minutes -->
  </session-config>
```

In my Servlet, I attempt:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName, locale);
```

It returns null.

In my JettyWeb, right after server.start() I attempt:

```
URL rs = this.getClass().getResource(propertiesDir);
System.out.println("Found: " + rs.toString());
```

It also returns null.
Although I didn't believe that one would work.

Any help would be much appreciated please.

Comment: try with a folder $jetty.home/resources/yourbundle.properties

Comment: With $jetty.home I'm assuming you mean the war directory?  So in my case [war directory]/resources/bundle.properties

Comment: Information provided about _how_ you access these bundles is not clear.  You have many classloaders in play here, the calls to `this.getClass().getResource()` and `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` should all occur from within the Servlet contexts and scopes (like a ServletContextListener or a Servlet.init or Servlet request).  Attempts to access this information from outside of these scopes will result in null.

Comment: Ok I'll try to be more clear. I'll try and edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties properties;
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
properties = new Properties();
properties.load(inputStream);
String value = properties.getProperty(key);
```

This works in my case with embedded-jetty and `application.properties` is on classpath